# Multiple orphan branches or separate repositories - git

Tags: git, github, workflow, git-branch

I have a project which I would like to store on GitHub.

This project contains code to run on an Arduino, Android, iOS as well as server code. Each section of the code interacts with the other, however, development of each section is more or less independent.

Should I have all the code sections in one repository under different orphan branches, or should I have a separate repository for each section? Why? What would be the advantages and inconveniences of each method?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer your self with the question following.

So splitting backend, microservices and UI app, android app, ios app(even when they are different parts) is not very sensible, due to the high dependency on each other if your answer is yes to below questions.

1. Are the multiple parts developed by the same team?
2. Have the same release cycle?
3. Is each project partially dependent on the other to release or revert?

Opt for multiple repositories when you say yes to the following?

1. A single repository would be too large to be efficient.?
2. Your repositories are loosely coupled, or decoupled.?
3. A developer typically only needs one, or a small subset of your repositories to develop.?
4. Different teams work on different repositories.

There are many more question to ask yourself still. There is no predefinded pattern for individual cases.

Answer (score 3):

If the branches are totally and "eternally" independent, use independent repositories.

There's absolutely no benefit in mixing them in a single repository that will grow bigger than any single "branch" really needs.

Smaller repository - less clone time, less stress soon gc, less overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. They are not totally independent since the Arduino will be communicating with the phones and the phones with the server. Taking that into account, would there be advantages to using branches?

Comment: @SUPERETDUPER - personally I still consider this as independent from a repository perspective. The branches won't have any merge points.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll wait a couple days to see if there are any other answers. If not I'll mark yours as correct.